# One code base for parsing XML in .NET 2.0 and Silverlight 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, silverlight

We need to parse XML's in our components (EasyQuery.NET). 
Some base classes of those components must work in all .NET versions starting from version 2.0 and now in Silverlight as well.
The problem is that XmlDocument class we used before is not included into Silverlight stack of classes. It's quite weird from Microsoft's side to use the same namespace (System.XML) both in .NET 2.0 and Silverlight but with different set of classes.
Anyway, could someone suggest what classes for XML parsing will be compiled well (maybe with little changes) both in .NET 2.0 (and higher) and Silverlight 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible; .NET 2.0 only has `XmlDocument`; SL only has `XDocument`.

Options:

- use `XmlReader` (hard to do robustly, to be honest)
- write an abstraction over the two, and use a compiler symbol or similar to switch
- update your minimum requirements to 3.5 SP1 or higher (it would be in 3.5 too, but 3.5 is [now technically unsupported](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/Default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=.NET%20Framework) (since 12/07/2011); 3.5 SP1 is is minimum officially supported version of .NET)

Comment: Oops, missed the 2.0 bit. I've nuked my dodgy incorrect answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As for now we are going to try XmlReader. 
It seems it has similar (or even equal) functionality in both .NET and Silverlight. Moreover XmlReader works faster and takes less memory than XmlDocument or XDocument what can be quite important in case of Silverlight.